# php foreach loops only once with dynamica data

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop, str-replace

I would like the output to be displayed like this:

category1
subcategory1.1
subcategory1.2

category2
subcategory2.1
subcategory2.2

Etc...

I believe it is an issue with str_replace()
I'm not sure where the issue is, could someone lend a hand?

Here is the code:

```
class temp 
{
var $file;

function get_file($temp){
$this->file = get_file_contents($temp)
return $this->file;
}

function new_list($forum_list)
{
    foreach($forum_list as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->file = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->file);
    }
    return $this->file;
}

function display()
{
    echo $this->file;
}
}

 $temp = new temp();

$temp->get_file('file.html');

mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_cat = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY dsp ASC";
$cat = mysql_query($query_cat, $config) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row_cat = mysql_fetch_array($cat)){
    $temp->new_list(array(
        'CAT_TITLE' => $row_cat['title'],
        'CAT_DESCRIPTION' => $row_cat['description']));

    $cid = $row_cat['id'];


mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
$query_cat = "SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE cid={$cid}";
$subcat = mysql_query($query_subcat, $config) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row_subcat = mysql_fetch_array($subcat)){
        $temp->new_list(array(
            'SUBCAT_TITLE' => $row_subcat['title'],
            'SUBCAT_DESCRIPTION' => $row_subcat['description']));
    }
}
$temp->display();
```

Comment: If the database is setup right, you should be able to pull the categories out of the database in the way you want them displayed. I would refer you to this: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: i have tried that also but doesn't work and i have many similar name for the fields in both the tables like title and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I can see is:

```
$this->file = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->file);
```

You are overwriting your `$file` variable in every iteration and apart from that you are never actually setting the `$file` so as far as I can see, it should be empty after running your code.

Comment: You're right. I guess this line throws 'Undefined variable' notice or something like that. +1

Comment: Sorry but i know that its overwriting how do i get it right i just can think of it no more and i don't have much time to take a day off and then later on think about it...

Comment: @wh1t3h4ck5 - No it only displays the values once and then goes out of the loop or overwrites only the first category once just need a way to improve it and display it properly...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, then you have to append str_replace's output to a different variable rather than the original $file:

```
class temp 
{
var $file;
var $output;

  function new_list($forum_list)
  {
    foreach($forum_list as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->output .= str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $this->file);
    }
    return $this->output;
  }

  function display()
  {
    echo $this->output;
  }
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't work instead i does not even replace a few more variables

Comment: Could you then please give us an example what's inside this `$file`.

Comment: the $file is getting contents from file.html that is like: <h1>{CAT_TITLE}</h1><BR /> {SUBCAT_TITLE}

Comment: First of all - does the query part of your script work? If you replace the `$temp->new_list` part with `var_dump` in both locations, does it give you, what you expect? If it does, then my snippet should work too - it merely takes $file, replaces parts that match _$keys_ and then appends the output to another variable _$output_.

Comment: BTW, you keep talking about subcategories, but your query does not seem to fetch them from DB. Please edit your question with a sample of the actual output from your script.

Comment: yes if i use static values then if matches and replaces correctly i mean without database and i will edit the question and show the correct code snippet...